# Upload Audio file using Retrofit to flask api

Tags: android, audio, flask, retrofit

I am trying to use sound for processing so I need the sound to be uploaded from android device to API (Flask).

I used MultiPart with a retrofit call is successfully sent but at API side not detect file

retrofit

```
@POST("uploadfile")
    @Multipart
    Call<MLResponse> upload(@Part("file")RequestBody file);
```

request body

```
 requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("title", "Square Logo")
                .addFormDataPart("file", "aa.mp4",
                        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, new File(path)))
                .build();
```

API

```
@app.route('/uploadfile',methods=['GET','POST'])
def uploadfile():
     # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return jsonify( result = "No file")
        try:
            file = request.files['file']
            return jsonify( result = str(file.filename)
        except :
            return jsonify( result = "Error")
```

the result is `No file` however 
I have checked the file using `file.exists()` it returns true and able to play it.

Answer (score 0):

In your API code you have no code for saving this file. Check this code and add the necessary lines.

```
@app.route('/uploadfile',methods=['GET','POST'])
def uploadfile():
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        f = request.files['file']
        filePath = "./somedir/"+secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(filePath)
        return "success"
```

Comment: `no code for saving this file` I am facing problrm of file not being accepted from api side so. no file to save.